# Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, lts

When I try to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, using graphical interface, I keep getting the same error:
[Authentication failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpRVU.png)

Authenticating the upgrade failed. There might be a problem with the network or with the server.

The network works great, the server works as well, but the error keeps showing up.

What could cause this, and what should be the next steps?

P.S. I saw a bunch of answers to similar questions, but none really helped. New at Ubuntu, completely ignorant.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this error come up after you enter the password you are prompted for?

Comment: @David yes, and the password was accepted. I'm also the 'root' user, or however it's called, not sure. Like an admin.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1262749/66509 . Are you use this machine behind proxy?